# Does anyone have background on the java annotation "java.lang.Synthetic"?

Tags: java, annotations

Does anyone have background on the java annotation "java.lang.Synthetic".  I'm encountering it while listing annotation occurrences in a JavaEE Enterprise Application.  The annotation occurs on a couple of classes in package com.sun.xml.  I am finding no documentation for this annotation.  Is it an official annotation, say, produced by the java compiler to indicate a synthetic accessor (see, for example, [Synthetic accessor method warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501324/synthetic-accessor-method-warning))?  That seems unlikely, since no documentation is available.  However, placement in package "java.lang" gives the annotation somewhat of an official look.

Comment: Are you sure it's in `java.lang`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-synthetic-class-method-field/

Comment: Hi.  That explains about synthetic methods, but is not what I'm looking for.  I looking for the meaning of "java.lang.Synthetic" as an annotation.  Is this in any way an official annotation?  Is it a one time (and probably incorrect) creation of sun tooling?  I ask because the annotation lives in package "java.lang", which gives it the look of an official / language or specification defined annotation.

Answer (score 0):

A perusal of ASM shows this to be a "virtual" parameter annotation added by ASM.

See:

http://asm.ow2.org/index.html

http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fasm%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2FClassReader.java

With:

```
private void readParameterAnnotations(int v, final String desc,
        final char[] buf, final boolean visible, final MethodVisitor mv) {
    int i;
    int n = b[v++] & 0xFF;
    // workaround for a bug in javac (javac compiler generates a parameter
    // annotation array whose size is equal to the number of parameters in
    // the Java source file, while it should generate an array whose size is
    // equal to the number of parameters in the method descriptor - which
    // includes the synthetic parameters added by the compiler). This work-
    // around supposes that the synthetic parameters are the first ones.
    int synthetics = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc).length - n;
    AnnotationVisitor av;
    for (i = 0; i < synthetics; ++i) {
        // virtual annotation to detect synthetic parameters in MethodWriter
        av = mv.visitParameterAnnotation(i, "Ljava/lang/Synthetic;", false);
        if (av != null) {
            av.visitEnd();
        }
    }
    for (; i < n + synthetics; ++i) {
        int j = readUnsignedShort(v);
        v += 2;
        for (; j > 0; --j) {
            av = mv.visitParameterAnnotation(i, readUTF8(v, buf), visible);
            v = readAnnotationValues(v + 2, buf, true, av);
        }
    }
}
```