# Why is the data array in java.util.ArrayList package-private?

Tags: java, arraylist, visibility, inner-classes

In the `java.util.ArrayList` class, the object array for the list's elements is defined as package-private:

```
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access
```

The comment states that the reason why this field is not private is easier access in nested classes. However, nested classes can access private data of the enclosing class just fine. So why is `elementData` not private? Is there something happening in the background (e.g., at compilation time)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you access a private field from a nested class, the compiler actually generates a [synthetic accessor method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-synthetic#synthetic-methods) that is package-visible, and then uses that for the access. It can't access the private member directly, so to avoid that indirection you can make the member package-visible instead.

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226833/1849769) with more details.

Comment: [it is different since jdk-11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67340214/1059372)

Answer (score 12):

That comment is outdated. With the introduction of [this JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181), there will be no syntactic method created by the compiler anymore; and that was introduced in `jdk-11`.

*Before* that change, the problem for such a highly used structure like `ArrayList`, was that another method in the call-stack (for accessing that `private` field) could potentially have a high cost in critical paths. To get aways from calling one more method, you could declare the field *without* `private`.

Comment: The code of `ArrayList` and other classes doesn't seem to be updated to take advantage of the nest-mate functionality. [This mail](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2021-May/077275.html) to a JDK mailing list suggests making such updates.

Answer (score -1):

> However, nested classes can access private data of the enclosing class
> just fine

This is not true for nested classes that are `static`.

And at least the class `ArrayList.SubList` is `static` and accesses `elementData`.

also see here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

**What I claimed here is plain wrong as @tevemadar made clear to me.
This is a working example that @tevemadar provided:**

```
public class Test
{
    private int a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Inner().doTest(new Test());
    }

    static class Inner
    {
        void doTest(Test t)
        {
            System.out.println(t.a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a constraint/feature of `static` what you probably mean. A static inner class can't access fields of the outer object directly because there is no outer object (as for `static` things in general). That's why the article writes about the need of an object reference.

Comment: Yes, that is a feature of static. 
But ArrayList.Sublist can't access dataElement, since it is a static class. So it acccesses it via a reference of ArrrayList, called root. And that does only work if elementData is package private.
And the original question was, why that field is package protected and not private.

Comment: *And that does only work if elementData is package private.* - Nope, it would work with an explicit `private` too. Try this: `public class Test {private int a=0;public static void main(String[] args){new Inner().doTest(new Test());}static class Inner{void doTest(Test t){System.out.println(t.a);}};}`

Comment: You are right. Thanks for beeing so tenacious. That helped me to get rid of my false assumption.